# Android java button value check

Tags: java, android, android-button

I'm trying to learn basic stuff in android studio with java. I need to create 1 activity where we need a Button and a text to input. When the button is clicked to check is the input value is between 3 words "Primary, Secondary , Higher). Here is the mainactivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button;
private int check = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    // Check for valid education


    // if yes -> next view
    if (check == 0 ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if ( check == 1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: so what do you really want?

Comment: where is the edit text ?  do want  to get input from user or static?

Comment: - when the button is pressed to check:
- Education to have a value (Primary, Secondary, Higher)
- In case of invalid values, error messages are displayed
- Enter education (Primary, Secondary, Higher)
- If valid values are entered, the second asset is passed

I didnt created input field because i dont know how to check the values

Comment: how did you created button ?

Comment: Button is created via activity.xml file? I have created the second activity. The button works , and passes to the second activity. I need to add in the main activity text input and the text to be validated. If users enter like random words ,  it will get error Please enter ,(Primary, Secondary, Higher).  If he enters the (Primary, Secondary, Higher) , it will display correct education and to pass the 2nd activity. I suggest i need to use the EditText, but i dont know how to make the validation with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this way

add input field in you xml file above button view .

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/edu"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Enter your education" />
```

In your `mainactivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button;
private EditText edu; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edu = findViewById(R.id.edu);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

  button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
 
      @Override
       public void onClick(View v){

       String check_edu= edu.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

      if ( check_edu.equals("primary") || check_edu.equals("secondary") || check_edu.equals("higher") ){
           startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
                   
              } else {
                   Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }

            });


  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't give compilation errors , i tried with random word worked. But it doesn't accept the correct word. Even if the word is correct it doesn't pass the 2nd activity? Or i have mistake somewhere did u tested it?

Comment: try again I have edited